# How to bridge an arched surface

Tags: python

I am new to Blender 3d and I want to give my model a thickness

Typically, SOLIDIFY modifiers can achieve, there are some differences here.

The cross-section of my model is as I drew, it looks like a big cylinder connected to a small cylinder. SOLIDIFY modifiers will give the two cylinder thickness, but what I actually want is only the big one

[image]

you can get my blend file from https://gofile.io/d/qzvvQF and I already extrude the bottom edge along the normal direction

Comment: Is that a Python question or a modelling/mesh question?

Comment: @lemon It finally will be a python question, but if it can be achiever by modeling, I also will try my best to code the solution